# Как в объекте типа data.frame отобрать переменные только одного типа?

Tags: r, data.frame

Например, имеется большой массив данных >100 переменных. А мне необходимо отобрать  лишь количественные. Как можно сделать подобное?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предварительно стоит изучить структуру данных с помощью функции `str()`.

Выполнить поставленную Вами задачу можно следующим образом:

```
sapply(DF, is) # классы столбцов
DF[, sapply(DF, is.numeric)] # все столбцы класса numeric
DF[, sapply(DF, is.factor)] # все столбцы класса factor
DF[, sapply(DF, is.character)] # все столбцы класса character
```

Можно также использовать комбинацию `sapply` + `which`: `DF[, which(sapply(DF, is.numeric))]`. В некоторых случаях данный вариант показывает более высокую производительность.

Также стоит отметить, что для числовых переменных могут применяться разные классы: `integer` (целые числа), `double` (числа с плавающей запятой) или `numeric` (включает в себя два предыдущих типа). Это может пригодиться, если, например, необходимо отфильтровать только столбцы, содержащие целые числа.

Answer (score -1):

`df_numeric <- df[ , sapply(df, is.numeric)]`

Создание нового дата фрейма `df_numeric` только с количественными данными из исходного `df`.

`is.numeric` проверяет столбцы на предмет того, являются ли они количественными